# 3D scene from two video files from two different angles

Tags: 3d, computer-vision, kinect, primesense

I have 2 video files of a scene from two different angles and I want to reconstruct a 3D estimation of the scene. It is similar to what 3D sensors do (e.g. Kinect, PrimeSense). I am looking for a library or even a well-established machine vision algorithm so that I can implement an API myself. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570188/3d-model-construction-using-multiple-images-from-multiple-points-kinect?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use only one video file:

You can use Visual SFM (based on bundler and cmvs) to create a dense 3D reconstruction:

http://ccwu.me/vsfm/

You can also use PMVS in conjunction with Bundler to produce a dense point cloud: http://www.di.ens.fr/pmvs/
http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~snavely/bundler/

And there's also the SFM+CVMS distribution for windows (again, producing a dense point cloud): https://code.google.com/p/osm-bundler/downloads/detail?name=osm-bundler-pmvs2-cmvs-full-32-64.zip